# How Can I Save Multiple Check Box Value Into Different Rows In SQL Database By Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, checkbox, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a form like image below :
[image: 1]
I have Multiple Value with **set_name(Numbers 1 2 3 ...) and set_value(0 OR 1).**
This is my database table :
[image: 2]

For example if i checked Number 1 And Number 2 And Number 6 and then clicked on save button .
At first check that is there a value with the name that i checked, in **set_name** in database or not, if there is a value**(set_name)** , update **set_value of that to 1** else if there isn't any set_name and any row with that name , **create a row** with names Number 1,Number 2 and Number 6 then set their set_value to 1
How can i do this work with laravel?

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change your table design, setting the primary key or unique index on the `set_name` field.

Then, you could use a SQL that will do INSERT if `set_name` isn't in your table, and UPDATE if `set_name` is in the table. The SQL to this job is explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO t1 (set_name, set_value) VALUES ('$cb_name', '$cb_value')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set_name = '$cb_name', 
                        set_value = '$cb_value';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kiks73 but I want to code in laravel not PHP!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="Number 1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="value[Number 1]" value="1" />
    Number 1
</label>
```

You can use the `firstOrCreate` method:

```
$values = Request::get('value');
foreach(Request::get('name') as $name) {
    // PHP 7+
    $newValue = $values[$name] ?? 0;
    // PHP <7
    //$newValue = isset($values[$name]) ? 1 : 0;
    Settings::firstOrCreate(['set_name' => $name], ['set_value' => $newValue]);
}
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods):

> The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the attributes from the first parameter, along with those in the optional second parameter.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, When I Use Only 1 Input Your Code Works Great ! but when i use multiple inputs like below :  your code doesn't work and it only create with the first input name and value 0! like the image >>![3](https://i.imgur.com/dhvAW0t.png) how can i use your code for more than 1 input? thanks

Comment: ```<label><input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="Number 1"/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="value[Number 1]" value="1"/>
                                    Number 1
                                </label>
                               <label>                                 <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="Number 2"/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="value[Number 2]" value="1"/>
                                    Number 2
                                </label> ... 
                                ```